# Stop WebSphere Liberty server if application fails to start

Tags: websphere-liberty

I'm looking for an option to stop my Liberty server if a specific application fails to start.

I can't find any option for this in the docs, the closest thing I've found to achieve this is health policies but they don't look to be a good fit.

Comment: Just curious, why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could write something (even as simple as a bash script) to check the logs for:
"CWWKZ0001I: Application {appName} started" 
and if you don't see it in x time, then execute "/wlp/bin/server stop {serverName}"

Could do it all through mbean invocations via java or REST calls by checking the state of the app (WebSphere:service=com.ibm.websphere.application.ApplicationMBean,name=*) and if it's not 'Started' by x time, then invoke an api to stop it (for collective environment you could use WebSphere:feature=collectiveController,type=ServerCommands,name=ServerCommands, otherwise you could use the osgi framework api).